# Docker build failure with Elysia, Bun, and Prisma

Tags: docker, bun

I'm attempting to dockerize an application using Elysia, Bun, and Prisma for deployment on render.com. When running a local docker build, I encounter an error related to Prisma generation.

**Error:**

```
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c bunx prisma generate" did not complete successfully: exit code: 9
```

Additionally, when trying to build on my host, I receive:

```
error: Cannot find module ".prisma/client/index" from "/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/index.js"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM oven/bun

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY bun.lockb .
COPY prisma .

RUN bun install --production

COPY src src
COPY tsconfig.json .

RUN bunx prisma generate

ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["bun", "src/index.ts"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

I've followed the documentation from Elysia and added the Prisma command. I've tried installing Prisma separately within the container and experimented with different command orders. Being relatively new to Docker and aiming for deployment on render.com, I'm unsure what I'm missing or doing incorrectly. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. I also tried to `RUN cp /usr/local/bin/bun /usr/local/bin/node` and running prisma from local node_modules folder.

Comment: I edited the dockerfile to copy everything over 
```FROM oven/bun:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package.json

COPY bun.lockb bun.lockb

RUN bun install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["bun", "src/index.ts"]
```

Now it builds locally but when i depoy it to render.com it still fails with the same error

Comment: Not a final solution, but i ended up with using `FROM node:latest` and then installing bun into it globally, and then it worked
The important part is: 
`ENV PNPM_HOME /usr/local/share/pnpm
ENV PATH $PNPM_HOME:$PATH
RUN corepack enable
RUN corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
RUN pnpm install -g bun`

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: @Vega I apologize for the oversight. I'll ensure my questions are programming-related in the future. Can you suggest a more appropriate platform or forum for my question?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case another noob like me stumbles upon the same problem :)

Changed location of the prisma client

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/client"
}
```

Solved the issue, the generated prisma client does not have to be generated new within the container but is just copied over.

```
FROM oven/bun

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY bun.lockb .

RUN bun install --production

COPY src src
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY prisma prisma

# COPY public public

ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["bun", "src/index.ts"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
error: Cannot find module ".prisma/client/index"
```

I was have same problem, and I think this is because we need to do bunx prisma generate, but the images oven/bun doesn't yet to handle that, sometime error, but sometime no error, but still not working.

so I try to just copy source from node_modules/.prisma and send to node_modules/.prisma in docker container

```
FROM oven/bun:1.0.15-debian
WORKDIR /app

# first i run : bun run build before creating docker image
COPY /build /app/build

# copy prisma configuration // This is your Prisma schema file,
COPY /prisma /app/prisma

COPY bun.lockb package.json /app/
RUN bun i --production

# some time error: lockfile had changes, but lockfile is frozen
# sove this error:
# run: bun install && bun install --frozen-lockfile
# this will regenerate your bun.lockb 


# RUN bunx prisma generate was error:undefined
# I copy my node_modules/.prisma into dockerfile 
# so doesn't need to do bunx prisma generate

COPY ["/node_modules/.prisma", "/app/node_modules/.prisma"]

EXPOSE 3000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT [ "bun", "run", "build/index.js" ]
```

And if your os is different maybe it required to do somting like this on your prisma schema setting

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}
```

depends on your bun images,

I Hope this can solve your problem too

Answer (score 0):

Bun might be having a path finding issue. This worked for me.
Edit your schema.prisma file

```js
generator client {
   provider = "prisma-client-js"
   output = "../generated"
   binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}
```

Save. Generate new definitions by running `bunx prisma generate`

Now your **generated** folder is in the root of your project. Use your IDE to search for **all** mentions of `"@prisma/client"` in your source code files, rename `"@prisma/client"` to `"generated"`

Be sure to copy over the generated folder into your Dockerfile with something like

```
COPY generated generated
```